# c# map printer with cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line, network-printers

If they click on the button form will pop up they write the printer name what is on the server and click the button and then cmd map the printer, but the "\" mix it up. How should I fix it up?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    string printer = textBox1.Text;
    string CMD = "/c start \\servername\" + printer;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", CMD);

}
```

Comment: If the printer has an IP address you can use the address and skip the server name.  You code is starting the print queue service for the printer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a \ to delimit every \ in your string:

So

```
string CMD = "/c start \\\\servername\\" + printer;
```

You can also use a verbatim string literal as pointed out by [stuartd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuartd)

```
string CMD = @"/c start \\servername\" + printer;
```

Comment: Or `@"/c start \\servername\" + printer` which I personally think is easier to read.